# Kiel traduki "plain text" (nur-teksta dosierformo)?

Tags: single-word-requests, information-technology

How to translate "**plain text**" in an IT/CS context, not referring to the cryptographic meaning (non-cyfer text) but just **as opposed to "rich text"** (such as RTF, MS Word or LibreOffice Writer) and as opposed to "binary" formats (such as BMP)?

[Komputeka](https://komputeko.net/index_de.php?vorto=plain+text) and [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plata_teksto) suggest *"plata teksto"* for that meaning, but is that the accepted and most-understood way to express this in Esperanto?

Answer (score 3):

Kelkaj homoj tradukas "**plain text**" per "*kruda teksto*". Mi trovas tiun tradukon pli bona pro la klara signifo de "*kruda*":

([ReVo](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/krud.html)) (grasigo de mi)

> Tia, kia la naturo ĝin produktis, konservanta sian **primitivan staton**;
>   a)
>   **Neprilaborita**, **nepreparita**, nekulturita

Mi ne komprenas kiel "*plata teksto*" estas "*plata*". Sed ja ekzistas homoj kiuj tradukas tiel.

Answer (score 0):

The English adjective "plain" can have [various meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plain#Adjective) depending on context. I suspect that "plata teksto" comes from interpreting it as "flat" or "level" (meaning No. 1 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=plain&oldid=51583491#Adjective)), but in my opinion there's nothing inherently more "flat" about plain text than about other types / formats of text in IT.

I think "simple" (meaning No. 2 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=plain&oldid=51583491#Adjective), actually having "plain text" listed as sub-meaning 2.5) fits the intended properties better, but "simpla teksto" would probably be mistaken to refer to the complexity (or lack thereof) of the text's content or phrasing. I find sub-meaning 2.4 (of food) quite close in concept:

> Having only few ingredients, or no additional ingredients or seasonings; not elaborate, without toppings or extras.

And if I had to invent or establish a new term to capture that, I think it'd be **"pur-teksto"** / **"purteksto"** or **"pura teksto"**. And indeed, another vikipedio article uses just that: [Listo de finaĵoj de dosiernomo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listo_de_fina%C4%B5oj_de_dosiernomo)